# Question on proof of coin-tossing in "how to simulate it"

Tags: multiparty-computation

I am reading Professor Lindell's "[How To Simulate It - A Tutorial on the Simulation Proof Technique](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf)" paper, which is very enlightening.

I am trying to follow through the proof of the security of Blum's coin-tossing protocol and have some questions: in the end of page 41 it says ": Let $b_1$ be the value committed in the commitment $c$ sent by $A$ (since $A$ is **deterministic** and this is the first message, this is a fixed value)."

1. I don't understand why we can assume $A$ is deterministic?
2. In general, should the security proof work for probabilistic adversaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are deterministic adversaries as powerful as probabilistic adversaries?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60580/are-deterministic-adversaries-as-powerful-as-probabilistic-adversaries)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a probabilistic adversary $A$ can be viewed as a deterministic adversary with a random tape: $A$ just picks a random string in the beginning and then run deterministically according to that fixed string. In the proof, the simulator $S$ uses the real-world adversary $A$ as a black box but can control its random tape (because a random tape always contains fair random strings that can be generated by anyone). So, $S$ can simulate the output of a probabilistic adversary $A$ by first choosing a random string $r$ then dealing with the resulting deterministic adversary $A'=A(r)$.